# Is there any way to share a files/folders via a link without authentication when using Nextcloud?

Tags: nextcloud

Is there some way to publicly share files/folders using NextCloud?

I am using Nextcloud 15.0.2 on an Ubuntu server and I want to be able to share files and folders with people outside of my company (nothing confidential, just some images) but I do not want them to have to authenticate in order to view/download the files.

Sort of like in Dropbox where they have the feature where you share a folder, it gives you a URL and you can give that URL to anyone and they can access files without having a Dropbox account.

I don't really care if this functionality is native or via a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is - to my knowledge it is usually enabled by default, but it may have to be enabled by the administrator.  The [File Sharing](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/configuration_files/file_sharing_configuration.html) documentation covers how to enable it - specifically, in the Admin page in the Sharing section:

> Check `Allow users to share via link` to enable creating public shares for people who are not Nextcloud users via hyperlink.

I found a strange problem with viewing the actual button to create the link for an individual file: if an adblocker was enabled, that hid the UI (even though the adblocker did not report any blocked elements).  See [Share via public link button not showing #13521](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/13521) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

All this functionality is already out of box.
Backup and try to upgrade NC to the latest stable version. [How to upgrade](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/maintenance/upgrade.html)
In case of issues will have go in a hard way - fresh install and migrate all data from v15*.